# How to get process/flow property values when in Salesforce Process Builder

Tags: process-builder, visual-workflow

Is it possible to get any of the values for these Process/Flow properties:

1. Flow Version
2. Current Flow Version
3. Flow Interview Guid
4. Interview Id
5. Flow Name (i.e. 00002463)

From within Process Builder?

So I could post them to chatter so I could debug.

Comment: Not sure about it but theoretically speaking you can query for [FlowDefinition](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_flowdefinition.htm) using [Apex tooling api](https://github.com/afawcett/apex-toolingapi) (Call a invocable method from process or flow to make a call)

Comment: @codeyinthecloud What property/value does Process Builder provide to me, such that I can query FlowDefinition and get the information I require?

Comment: It doesn't provide you anything afaik you will have to go for hardcoded developerName in your where it's your current process

Comment: @codeyinthecloud developer name won't get the information specific to the version of the actual process executing.

Comment: ActiveVersion and ActiveVersionId on the flowDefinition where DeveloperName is your current process name(this piece should be hardcoded using the api name in the properties), Not sure if I'm confusing you are may be my thought process is wrong!

Comment: @codeyinthecloud I want to be able debug scheduled actions using older versions than the currently active ones.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85462/discussion-between-codeyinthecloud-and-robs).